# Create new unique value in column

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, unique-values

I have a (MYSQL) table in the following format; assume the name of the table is `mytable`:

| id | name | group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | name1 | 1 |
| 124 | name2 | 2 |
| 125 | name3 | 1 |
| 126 | name4 |  |

`id` is unique and auto-increments. `name` is a unique string, `group` is just an integer

I now want to assign `name4` to a new `group` that does not exist yet, so the `group` for `name4`cannot be `1` or `2` in this example.

The result could,for example, be:

| id | name | group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 126 | name4 | 3 |

At the moment I am sorting by `group` descending and just insert the highest number + 1 manually, but I was wondering if there was a better/quicker way to generate a new, unique value in a column. `group` has no other constraints, besides being an integer.

I am using the MySQL Workbench, so I can work with both SQL commands, as well as Workbench-specific options, if there are any.

If anything is unclear I'll gladly provide clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 8.0, you can get help with two window functions:

- `MAX`, to retrieve the maximum "*group*" value
- `ROW_NUMBER`, to retrieve the incremental value for each NULL existing in your table.

You can then sum up these two values and update your table where your "*group*" field is null.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id, name, MAX(group_) OVER() + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY group_ IS NULL ORDER BY name) AS new_group
    FROM tab
)
UPDATE tab 
INNER JOIN cte
        ON tab.id = cte.id AND tab.name = cte.name
SET tab.group_ = cte.new_group
WHERE tab.group_ IS NULL;
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gixKuHZEyqdk9oaNtnGFeW/0).

---

In MySQL 5.X you can instead use a variable, initialized with your maximum "*group*" value, then updated incrementally inside the `UPDATE` statement, in the `SET` clause.

```
SET @maxgroup = NULL;
SELECT MAX(group_) INTO @maxgroup FROM tab;

UPDATE tab 
SET group_ = (@maxgroup:= @maxgroup + 1)
WHERE group_ IS NULL;
ORDER BY id;
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gixKuHZEyqdk9oaNtnGFeW/2).